# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm writing an app that gets bugs from TFS.  When I run this program on my machine with visual studio installed Running Windows 8 it works fine.  When I run this program on one of my virtual machines Running Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 With the Visual Studio Agent installed it throws the following exception

```
Error occured: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at AutomationEntities.TFSManager.GetBugsFromTestCase(Int32 testCaseID)
   at AutomationEntities.ReportManager.GetBugStringFromTestCases(String testCaseString, String status)
   at AutomationEntities.ReportManager.InsertOrUpdateReport(String agentMachineName, String product, String versionName, String serverURL, String testCategory, String testName, String testNumber, String status, DateTime lastModifyTime, String errorMessage, Nullable`1 elapsedTime)
   at AutomationManager.XMLHandlerReport.AddItemToReportDatabase(String agentMachineName, String product, String version, String serverURL, String testCategory, String testName, TEST_STATUS testStatus, String errorMessage, String testNumber, String elapsedTime)
   at AutomationManager.ReportManager.ReportIndividualTestItem(TestData pendingTest, String testName, TEST_STATUS testStatus, String errorMessage, String resultsFileWPath)
   at AutomationManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

All of my machines run 64-bit Windows

I have no idea. The Dll listed is in the same folder as the app and it is version 11.  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with the GAC.  I just made all of my references build with the dlls instead of assuming they were in the GAC

**UPDATE:**

If you look into the properties of a reference there is a build property.  set all of the problem DLL's to copy on build.

Comment: and how did you do that? i have the same problem, and would like ot try your solution.

Comment: I feel like the entire c# community just... forgets how to explain "how" to do things.

Comment: I don't have a copy on build option. :-( I have Copy Local - but there is no hover text. :-(

Answer (score 21):

I had this same problem in an ASP.NET web application. I solved it by enabling `Enable 32-bit Applications` for the IIS application pool.

Comment: This is if you are making a web application.  Please note this in your comment.

Comment: More specifically, if building and running a web application using the Local IIS setting in Visual Studio (in your application's properties), fire up the IIS Manager in Windows, select Application Pools, right-click on DefaultAppPool, select Advanced Settings, and set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true. (Based on Windows 7, IIS7, Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 0):

I had recently faced the same problem with TFS 2010. I figured out that it was because of the target .Net Framework that my program was using. If you use 4.0 then while loading the dependencies of DatastoreLoader it tries to load some incorrect assemblies.

My problem was solved automatically when I used the correct target .Net Framework.
Hope this helps.

Comment: There are many things that can cause this for me it was just not copying the dlls.  Thanx for your post these dll problems are a PAIN!